# JavaScript Array Search and Remove

Tags: javascript, arrays, search

I have a scenario where I have an INPUT, The User enters some text, like for ex: Cat.
I need to search an Array and check if the input from the User is present in my Array.
If it is present I ould want to remove that item from the Array and return a new Array with that item removed.
Suppose I have an arraylist like,
let arrayList = ["cat","mouse","dog"];

User INPUT = cat;

I want to check if the cat is present in arrayList , If yes then I want to remove the cat from the arrayList and want to have a new array that does not contain cat in it. Hence any INPUT provided by User needs to be removed from an array and return me a new array without that item.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use filter function to filter the array. Reference link
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

```
function filterArray(arr, searchString) {
       var result = arr.filter(function(e) {
           return e != searchString;
       });
       return result;
}

filterArray(arrayList, "cat") // This will return ["mouse", "dog"];
```